# What is the meaning of "as" in "...as can be judged by..."?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, as

What does "as" mean in this sentence?

> But then something quite dramatic happened **as** can be judged by the
> many different animal groups that suddenly appear in the fossil
> record.

Besides, why “as” can be followed by “can” straightly?

Comment: You'll find this usage in the dictionary. In Websters, it is the third definition of "as": "when considered in a specified form or relation —usually used before a preposition or a participle my opinion as distinguished from his"

Comment: thank you, I see

Answer (score 1):

The meaning here is the same as if the sentence said

> But then something quite dramatic happened **as one can judge** by the many different animal groups that suddenly appear in the fossil record.

But instead of linking an active voice clause, the passive "as can be judged" was used.

1. The light is red, as you can see.
2. The light is red, as can be seen.

The first example uses "as" as a conjunction. In the second example, there is no explicit subject for the passive phrase "can be seen", so the word "as" seems to act as a pronoun, linking the fact that "the light is red" to its being seen. At least one dictionary calls "as" a pronoun in this sense:
[Merriam-Webster "as"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as)
pronoun 2. : a fact that
*is a foreigner, **as** is evident from his accent*

Note that in your original example, the pronoun "which" can be substituted with the same meaning:

> ...something quite dramatic happened, which can be judged by...

Comment: Thank you very much!